# Generics - Type parameter declaration must be an identifier not a type

Tags: c#, generics

On the first line, I get this compilation error.  "Type parameter declaration must be an identifier not a type.". Is there a way to fix this?

```
 public class ExtJsGridJsonModel<IEnumerable<T>>
{
    [DataMember(Name = "total")]
    public int Total { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "rows")]
    public IEnumerable<T> Rows { set; get; }

    public ExtJsGridJsonModel(IEnumerable<T> rows, int total)
    {
        this.Rows = rows;
        this.Total = total;
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Sorry for the lack of detail in my question and intentions. Basically, my end goal is to do this:

```
new ExtJsGridJsonModel<Company>();
```

rather than this:

```
new ExtJsGridJsonModel<IEnumerable<Company>>();
```

Basically, I want to reduce code by omitting the IEnumerable type. How do i do this?

Comment: You want @D Stanley's code then :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just take out the `IEnumerable` part of your declaration:

```
public class ExtJsGridJsonModel<T>
{
    [DataMember(Name = "total")]
    public int Total { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "rows")]
    public IEnumerable<T> Rows { set; get; }

    public ExtJsGridJsonModel(IEnumerable<T> rows, int total)
    {
        this.Rows = rows;
        this.Total = total;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you would be using this to store what is essentially a two dimensional set of values:

```
public class ExtJsGridJsonModel<T> where T : IEnumerable
{
    [DataMember(Name = "total")]
    public int Total { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "rows")]
    public IEnumerable<T> Rows { set; get; }

    public ExtJsGridJsonModel(IEnumerable<T> rows, int total)
    {
        this.Rows = rows;
        this.Total = total;
    }
}
```

If not, or `T` is actually a strongly-typed row class, then you can remove the `where T : IEnumerable` clause

Comment: Hence my comments before and after the code sample. How should I clarify this further?